# Consulta api giphy con javascript

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Tengo una duda, estoy iniciando con javascript y en una guía me dan un método para traer datos con fetch desde giphy. EL error que tengo es que al ejecutarlo con los datos requeridos me esta devolviendo un estado pendiente. Les comparto el código para que me orienten, puedo ver que si hago console a la variable data, los datos se están recibiendo pero la respuesta me da pendiente.

Les comparto la clase y el método que estoy usando, agradezco cualquier ayuda o guía.

```
class Giphy{

    constructor(search){
        this.apiKey = 'Ot8LkNZiCNqOlYdTfvzfCHNlwW4fgXxo';
        this.search = search;
    }


    getSearchResults(search) {
        const found =
        fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + this.search +
        '&api_key=' + this.apiKey)
        .then((response) => { return response.json() })
        .then(data => { return data })

        .catch((error) => {
        return error
        })
        return found
        }

}

const gif = new Giphy('gato');

console.log(gif.getSearchResults());
```

Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de `async/await`, aparte de que hará que tu código se vea limpio y organizado

```js
class Giphy{
  constructor(search) {
    this.apiKey = 'Ot8LkNZiCNqOlYdTfvzfCHNlwW4fgXxo';
    this.search = search;
  }
  async getSearchResults() {
    let api = await fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + this.search + '&api_key=' + this.apiKey);
    let found = await api.json();
    return found;
  }
}
const gif = new Giphy('gato');
gif.getSearchResults().then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
 });
```

**Editado**

Recuerda que las funciones que usan `async` siempre devuelven una promesa.

---

## Exporta e importa modulo para NodeJS

Para exportar un módulo para NodeJS, seria de la siguiente forma.

Creas un archivo llamado `Giphy.js`

```
// tu clase aquí...
module.exports = Giphy;
```

Para importarlo seria de esta forma

```
const Giphy = requiere('./Giphy.js');
const gif = new Giphy();
// ...
```

---

## Exportar e importar módulo para EcmaScript

Para exportar creas un archivo `Giphy.js`

```
// tu clase aquí...
export default Giphy;
```

Para importarlo seria así

```
import Giphy from './Giphy.js'
const gif = new Giphy();
// ...
```

**Ojo**

En caso de que desees exportar e importa módulos para ambas opciones, debes guardar los archivos `.js` en diferentes carpetas o con diferentes nombres. Para evitar errores

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirve mucho. 

Pero quiera saldar otra duda. Si deseo ejecutar esa clase con ese método getSearchResults() que están en un archivo llamado xx.js pero hacerlo desde otro archivo llamado yy.js, como debería hacer la importancia o como debería invocarla el archivo, la clase y el método? 

Mil gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @HELMER90 edite mi respuesta ;) cualquier cosa que no entiendas, dímelo y te ayudare ;)

Comment: Este es el resultado de exportar la clase e importarla desde otro archivo. 

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module app.js:2
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module giphy.js:38:2. 

Mi archivo principal se llama app.js y desde allí estoy tratando de importar la clase de giphy.js.

Comment: import Giphy from '/js/giphy.js'
const gif = new Giphy('gato');

gif.getSearchResults().then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
 });

y a continuación archivo giphy.js 

export default class Giphy{
    constructor(search) {
      this.apiKey = 'Ot8LkNZiCNqOlYdTfvzfCHNlwW4fgXxo';
      this.search = search;
    }
    async getSearchResults() {
      let api = await fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + this.search + '&api_key=' + this.apiKey);
      let found = await api.json();
      return found;
    }
  }

Comment: @HELMER90 `import Gyphy from './js/Giphy.js'` te hizo falta un punto al pricio, por eso te da error

Comment: Lo he puesto tal como me dices. import Giphy from './js/giphy.js'; y se mantiene el error. Por si ayuda, estoy trabajando con visual studio code y ejecuto el proyecto con live server en el navegador(chrome y mozilla). Solo uso index.html, index.css y los dos archivos javascripts. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @HELMER90 estas usan etiquetas `script` en tu html, para usar tu archivo `Giphy.js`. De ser así, asegurate de usar el atributo `type="module"`

Comment: Y tu etiqueta se vería así `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: Excelente, ese era el problema. Faltaba colocarle type="module". Muchas gracias por su ayuda y su tiempo. Bendiciones.

Comment: @HELMER90 no olvides darle en ✔ si esto respondió y resolvió tu pregunta

Comment: NO encuentro la opción para calificar como resulta la pregunta.